# solve the system using the Gaussian method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

$$
x_1-x_2+3x_3+4x_4+x_5=1
$$
$$
2x_1+7x_2+5x_3-2x_4 =4
$$
$$
x_1+8x_2+2x_3-6x_4-x_5=2
$$
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please do not ask volunteer strangers on the internet to just solve your homework. This is not how this works. Show what you have tried and clearly state where you are stuck, then we will be happy to help you out.

Comment: As your working shows, the system is inconsistent (looking at the final row of the final augmented matrix). From there, all other working is irrelevant: the system has no solution.

Comment: After your first row reduction to create zeros below the pivot you could simply subtract row 2 from row 3 to see that the new row 3 is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you follow your work but without using a matrix to try to make you understand what was said to you in the comments.
You should make a minimum of sentences to better understand what you are doing and where are the possible errors that are shown to you. I suggest for example:

*Suppose* $\color{blue}{\text{there are five real numbers}}$ which we will denote by $x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4$ and $x_5$ such that $$\begin{cases}x_1-x_2+3x_3+4x_4+x_5=1 \color{red}{ 
 (I)}\\2x_1+7x_2+5x_3-2x_4+0x_5=1\color{red}{ 
 (II)}\\x_1+8x_2+2x_3-6x_4-x_5=2\color{red}{ 
 (III)}\end{cases}$$
So like you did, $$\begin{cases}x_1-x_2+3x_3+4x_4+x_5=1 \color{red}{ 
 (I)}\color{green}{(I)}\\0x_1+9x_2-x_3-10x_4-2x_5=-1\color{red}{ 
 (II)-2\times(I)}\color{green}{(II)}\\0x_1+9x_2-x_3-10x_4-2x_5=1\color{red}{ 
 (III)-(I)\color{green}{(III)}}\end{cases}$$
Then, as @Paul told you, according to $\color{green}{(II)}$ and $\color{green}{(III)}$, $-1=9x_2-x_3-10x_4-2x_5=1.$ Then $-1=1$, what is wrong. So our $\color{blue}{\text{starting assumption}}$ is not possible.
In other words, there is no $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb R^5$ such that $\begin{cases}x_1-x_2+3x_3+4x_4+x_5=1 \\2x_1+7x_2+5x_3-2x_4+0x_5=1\\x_1+8x_2+2x_3-6x_4-x_5=2\end{cases}$

Otherwise written, the set $S$ defined by $S:=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb R^5:\begin{cases}x_1-x_2+3x_3+4x_4+x_5=1 \\2x_1+7x_2+5x_3-2x_4+0x_5=1\\x_1+8x_2+2x_3-6x_4-x_5=2\end{cases}\right\}=\varnothing$